# Long command at the end of list

Tags: spacing, enumitem

With `\setlist` option of package `enumitem` I'm trying to add some text at the end of an enumerated list. I'm also trying to center some part of this text, but some extra vertical space gets inserted. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist*[mylist]{label=\arabic*}
\setlist*[mylist]{after*=\endgraf
\bigskip
\bigskip
Some text some text
\begin{center}
some centered text
\end{center}
Some text some text
}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
With enumerate
\begin{mylist}
\item First item
\end{mylist}

Without enumerate (which looks like the thing I want to have):

1 First item\par
\bigskip
\bigskip
Some text some text
\begin{center}
some centered text
\end{center}
Some text some text

\end{document}
```

(`topsep` and `parskip` are set to 0 so extra space makes more difference)
I suppose long command inserted with `after=` to the end of the list generates error. Is there a way to put long command there properly?

I can force good-looking output with some negative `vspace` but I hope there is some more elegant solution.

EDIT: Thanks to comment by Phelype Oleinik I put `\endgraf` where I couldn't use `\par`. Spacing is now better, but still there is clearly some extra vertical space which I can't remove.

Comment: Use `\endgraf` where you can't use `\par`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler if you use a macro for `after`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist*[mylist]{label=\arabic*}
\setlist*[mylist]{after*=\addtext}

\newcommand{\addtext}{%
  \vspace*{\bigskipamount}
  \begin{center}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}% remove the vertical space
  Some text some text\hspace*{\fill}\par
  some centered text\par
  Some text some text\hspace*{\fill}
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want (I coloured the `after` part to visualise):

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{changepage, xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\newlength\labelwd
\settowidth{\labelwd}{0}
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist*[mylist]{label=\arabic*,start = 6}
\setlist*[mylist]{after*=\endgraf
\bigskip
\bigskip
\hspace*{\dimexpr\leftmargini-\labelsep-\labelwd\relax}\color{red}Some text some text \\
\null\hfill some centered text \hfill\null \\
Some text some text
}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
With enumerate
\begin{mylist}
\item First item
\end{mylist}

Without enumerate (which looks like the thing I want to have):

1 First item\par
\bigskip
\bigskip
Some text some text
\begin{center}
some centered text
\end{center}
Some text some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, as I said there is some added space between ,,some centered text'' and ,,some text''. I want to have no vertical space there (as in the example outside of the list). Fortunately, egreg's answer provided a solution to this.

Comment: @Tomasz23: I must say I overlooked the vertical spacing. Please see my updated code.

Comment: The output you presented is correct, however the code does not compile. I think you must have made typos in `\leftmargini` and `\labelwd`, since they are not recognised by the compiler.

Comment: As I replaced only what was modified in the code, maybe there were some typos. I've replaced with a full copy of my code, which naturally compiles for me.